# Hierarchy view does not display application activity

Tags: android, android-studio

I followed steps on [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html) i am Testing on physical device ,Android Device Monitor does not display activities of my application , it only display device name [image]

Comment: It seems your application is not started. Often a simple disconnect/reconnect solves the issue. Compile after and check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hierarchy View does not work with ordinary apps on production hardware. It works with the Android SDK emulator, and it may work on hardware if you [compile in `ViewServer`](https://github.com/romainguy/ViewServer).

Consider [using **`uiautomatorviewer`**](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html#inspecting-ui), as that works on production hardware.